# Literature on this kind of bias

Tags: references, bias

Suppose I'm trying to investigate the lifespan distribution of light bulbs. The catch is that I can only observe each bulb at most $T$ time units. So if the bulb doesn't blow before $T$ I will not know what the value of the lifespan would be for that specific bulb, only that its lifespan was larger than $T$.

So, the questions:

1. Is there a known name for this kind of bias?
2. Are there standard references to techniques to deal with this problem?

Comment: Look up censoring. Your data will be right-censored. Yes, there are methods that address this. Maximum likelihood in particular can be modified to handle your scenario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're talking about is known as "censoring" - specifically "right censoring" ("left censoring" is when the start time is unknown but the end time is known). The problem is endemic in the field of survival analysis. [This set of notes](http://www.amstat.org/chapters/northeasternillinois/pastevents/presentations/summer05_Ibrahim_J.pdf) gives details of the standard techniques for dealing with it, and contains a number of references to textbooks on the subject.